# tensorflow keras evaluate function

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, neural-network

How does the `evaluate` function really work and what exactly does it return?

Here is the interface definition for the `evaluate` from the documentation (from `tf.keras.models.Model`).

```
evaluate(
    x=None,
    y=None,
    batch_size=None,
    verbose=1,
    sample_weight=None,
    steps=None,
    max_queue_size=10,
    workers=1,
    use_multiprocessing=False
)
```

The documentation says that **the function returns the loss value & metrics values for the model in test mode.**

And 2 parameters have importance here:

> **batch_size**: Integer or None. Number of samples per gradient update. If
>   unspecified, batch_size will default to 32. Do not specify the
>   batch_size if your data is in the form of symbolic tensors, dataset,
>   dataset iterators, generators, or keras.utils.Sequence instances
>   (since they generate batches).
>
> **steps**: Integer or None. Total number of steps (batches of samples)
>   before declaring the evaluation round finished. Ignored with the
>   default value of None.

The documentation is a bit vague for me. I don't understand what is meant by the ***dataset*** in the sentence "Do not specify the
batch_size if your data is in the form of symbolic tensors, ***dataset***...."

In my case, my model has multiple inputs and the input `x` is a list of numpy arrays. My x looks like the following:

```
print(len(x))        returns   4
print(x[0].shape)    returns   (128, 9, 16)
```

The important thing is that the dataset (which is the train set in this example) has 128 examples in it.

While this is the case, I am very much confused regarding how I should be calling the evaluate function? I especially wonder how I should set the **batch_size** and **steps** parameters.

I can run it as following:

**Alternative 1:**

```
train_metrics = saved_model.evaluate(x          = train_x,
                                     y          = train_y,
                                     batch_size = None, 
                                     steps      = None)
```

Or I can run it as following as well:

**Alternative 2:**

```
train_metrics = saved_model.evaluate(x          = train_x,
                                     y          = train_y,
                                     batch_size = 64, 
                                     steps      = None)
```

What is the difference between 2 alternatives given that I have the dataset in the format I described above. I actually expect to see the same result ("loss" particularly) as the evaluate function should just go through the given dataset once and should give back the result for the entire dataset. But it is not happening. 2 alternatives above are giving dramatically different results.

Does anyone clearly know what the difference is between these 2 calls?

I tried to check the code as well but could not really figure out thi detail..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I don't understand what is meant by the dataset in the sentence "Do not specify the batch_size if your data is in the form of symbolic tensors, dataset...."

The dataset referred here is an instance of `tf.data.Dataset()`. A Dataset has its `batch_size` already defined. We define it using :

```
tf.data.Dataset.batch( batch_size )
```

Hence, there is no need of the argument in the Keras `evaluate` method.

> What is the `steps` argument?

Step size is the when the total number of samples are divided by the batch size. If I have 1000 samples and a batch_size of 50 then the number of steps would be 20 ( 1000 / 50 ). You do not need to enter the `steps` argument mostly.

**For 1st Alternative :**

Batch size is set to None. Hence, a default value of 32 will be used. Hence, here, as per the calculation the number of steps would be 4 ( 128 / 32 ).

**For 2nd Alternative :**

Batch size is set to 64. Hence, here, as per the calculation the number of steps would be 2 ( 128 / 64 ).

**Differences between the alternatives :**

Both alternatives have different batch sizes of 32 and 64. Hence, computation of loss and accuracy will be different.